# Oracle + reflection in IBM composer

Tags: grovers-algorithm

[image]

Can someone confirm, that this shows one oracle step and one reflection step for the Grover algorithm for 3 qubits, where the search item is hidden at position 5 (101) ?

Comment: You have only two working qubits, this means that you can search only for items 00, 01, 10 and 11. Qubit q2 is ancilla qubit and it is not part of the searched item number. In such setting, the reflection operator should work only on qubits q0 and q1. On qubit q2 you should have gates X and H followed by output of the oracle.

Comment: But how come, that the state vector for state 101 clearly dominates all others and if you add one more oracle and reflection iteration, it will dominate even more ? Do you have a circuit at hand with a better performance ?

Comment: Try this applet https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/QuantumCircuitImplementingGroversSearchAlgorithm